# Action Replay code to cut Jigglypuff's Rest sleep time in Super Smash Bro Melee?

Tags: cheats, super-smash-bros-melee

I'm trying to practice the [space animal slayer](http://ssbwiki.com/Space_animal_slayer) combo, but it's harder than I expected. It's annoying to wait for Jigglypuff to wake up and I have Action Replay (AR) for the GameCube.

I've searched the main AR codes websites, *arcentral.net* and *gscentral.org*, but I can't find a code to make Jigglypuff's Rest last a shorter duration.

Is there an AR code to cut the sleep time from Jigglypuff's Rest?

Comment: I would actually be surprised if there was a code for this considering I don't think we know how to edit action/animation length yet.

Comment: The Super Jigglypuff code speeds up Sing and Pound.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is 5 years old, but just in case you're still maining Jigglypuff and still need practice with this combo, I got something.

The 20XX mod now includes a way to save your current state and reload it instantly. For example, you could save you getting the grab on fox/falco, perform the combo, and then instantly reload the saved state of you having just grabbed the spacie, throw them up, down-b them, reload the saved state, do the combo, reload, combo, reload, etc.

A YT video detailing how this works can be found [here](https://youtu.be/TJ9TZt3CvOY?t=25).

From another Jiggs main,

Good luck! Go beat those spacies!